# Product matching query does not exist Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i am trying to insert product in my database using django custom fields, but it's showing me error that **Product matching query does not exist**.
it would be great if anybody could figure me out where should i make changes in my code. thank you so much in advance.

views.py

```
class ProductAdd(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):

        data = request.data
        title = data['title']
        slug = data['slug']
        description = data['description']
        # created_on = data['created_on']
        # status = data['status']

        queryset = Product.objects.filter(title__contains=title,slug__contains=slug,description__contains=description)
        query_slug = Product.objects.get(slug__exact=slug).first()

        try:
            if query_slug == None:
                # queryset.annotate(Count(title,slug,description,created_on,status))
                queryset.annotate()
                Response({"msg":"product added succesfully!"}, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                print("query already exist!")

        except ValueError:
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: You do a .get to get queryslug, should be a filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error said, it could not find a product based on given slug. To prevent this error from raising, you can use `.filter` instead of `.get`:

```
query_slug = Product.objects.filter(slug__exact=slug).first()
```

Also, I would recommend using a serializer to serialize and store data in DB. More information can be found in [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). Here is an example:

```
# serializer
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate_slug(self, value):
        if Product.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Product Exists")
        return value
# view
from rest_framework import generics    

class ProductAdd(generics.CreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```